# RuntimeError: Package installation failed, installed dependencies were rolled back

Tags: python, sql-server, spyder, sql-server-2017, sqlpackage

I was planning to execute python scripts in Sql Server Management Studio but first I have to install some missing library/packages first so the script can properly run. I was using sqlmlutils to install these python packages in SQL Server but there seems to be an error while running the following scripts:

```
import sqlmlutils
connection = sqlmlutils.ConnectionInfo(server="myserver", database="mydatabase", uid="myid", pwd="mypassword")
sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install("pandas-profiling")
```

And this is the error I'm getting from Spyder console:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Python'.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/.../Desktop/abc.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../Desktop')
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/abc.py", line 3, in 
>       sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install("pandas_profiling")
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlmlutils\packagemanagement\sqlpackagemanager.py", line 74, in install
>       self._install_from_pypi(package, upgrade, version, install_dependencies, scope, out_file=out_file)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlmlutils\packagemanagement\sqlpackagemanager.py", line 151, in _install_from_pypi
>       self._install_from_file(target_package_file, scope, upgrade, out_file=out_file)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlmlutils\packagemanagement\sqlpackagemanager.py", line 174, in _install_from_file
>       self._install_many(target_package_file, dependencies_to_install, scope, out_file=out_file)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlmlutils\packagemanagement\sqlpackagemanager.py", line 189, in _install_many
>       raise RuntimeError("Package installation failed, installed dependencies were rolled back.") from e
>
> RuntimeError: Package installation failed, installed dependencies were rolled back.

May I ask if anyone here had the same error? I am using Sql Server 2017 by the way. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have seen a couple of other reports like this. Let me check it out.

Comment: @NielsBerglund thank you!!